# Why we can't monitor future jobs in Salesforce

Tags: future

When we run a Future method we can find the Id and jobs in Apex jobs, then why we cont monitor in Salesforce.

Comment: You cab monitor your Async jobs. Please have a look at this trailhead
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_monitoring

Comment: I saw that link, my question here is What is the meaning of Monitoring in Salesforce exactly, in Apex jobs we can find Status, id other than this What is the monitoring

Comment: You can monitor the @future jobs in Salesforce UI, in the apex jobs. There you will find Future method name, apex class that has the method, job status, success and failures with submitted and completed datetime. So, what else do you want to know or monitor about your future jobs?

Comment: As per the salesforce comments, we con't monitor Salesforce future jobs ...         what Monitor is referenceing  here

Comment: Where does Salesforce comments that?

Comment: A link to the document that says that will provide a lot of context and help get you an answer

Comment: Monitoring of Jobs means you can get details as ApexClassId, CompletedDate, CreatedById, CreatedDate, ExtendedStatus, Id,
JobItemsProcessed, JobType, LastProcessed, LastProcessedOffset, MethodName, 
NumberOfErrors, ParentJobId, Status, TotalJobItems for all your Async Job. Please go through the document link shared on this trailhead for details

Comment: You do get all of that information in the apex jobs, as I mentioned in my comments earlier.